# Change order of "Generate toString"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

when I need a quick toString in my class I use VSCode's "generate toString" and check the fields.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-refactoring#_generate-tostring

but something annoying about this is that sometimes it's in an order that makes it annoying to debug. And fixing it in the function is just inconvenient.
Is there a way I can change the order so it'll show me:

`Class [foo="bar", bar="baz"]`

And not:

`Class [bar="baz", foo="bar"]`

Comment: Can you provide a simple code example?

Comment: @JialeDu when I have an object with another object as it's field(and that field has its own toString). Then I generate a toString to the object then if it comes first in the "Object[...]" and it's hard to read. Also let's say an object has a name and description, I want the name first then the description. It just helps a lot in debugging

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the class has an object as it's field, the fields shown in toString() generation might be in wrong order in the current vscode-java extension, see: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2502.

If the parameters in the toString() method are in the correct order (definition order), will it work for you?